# How to discard independent set for CF in some YouTrack project and start using common set of values?

Tags: youtrack

As an administrator of YouTrack I need sometimes create and discard independent set of values of custom fields. Creation of independent set is trivial: just use appropriate button, but what if I want to discard existing independent set and use common set of custom field values? Is it possible to do it in some easy way (through UI, API or command)?

For now, I have to add new custom field each time I need discard independent set. It happens not so often, fortunately.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Settings -> Custom Fields -> Fields in projects -> your project, 2. Expand it,
2. Select the field,
3. Delete unnecessary values by clicking on crosses,
4. Click "Copy values from.." button and select desired set of values in the dropdown.

Hope it helps.

[A screenshot of field settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28qjj.png)